# Camel-RabbitMQ : how to define an endpoint from a durable topic subscription?

Tags: apache-camel, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

Using Camel and its rabbitMQ module, how would I define an endpoint URL to a durable topic subscription? What options need to be set? what are corresponding options for what in camel JMS would be clientId and durableSubscriptionName?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rabbit-mq component found here:
http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html

The parameter exchangeType can be set to topic.

Very simple example:

```
from("rabbitmq://localhost/A?routingKey=B&exchangeType=topic")
```

Comment: does your answer imply that if i do not specify anything more than that URL the topic subscription would be a durable one? And how do I set the unique client ID? and is the topic name A or B in this example?

Comment: The exchange name is A and by setting exchangeType=topic I am telling Camel its a topic that I want to subscribe to. Otherwise it defaults to a direct exchange instead. It also depends on your requirements. If you set autoDelete=false, it will not delete the exchange afterwards. If the exchange already exists, set declare=false so it won't attempt to create it. There is a header called appid. You can use that to set unique client id.

Answer (score 0):

I found by experimentation that the exchange name to be used is "amq.topic", the routing key would be what would be the topic name and the queue name would be something unique based on the client id and the durable subscription name I would have used in JMS.

Souciance added correctly that the exchange type needs to be topic and autoDelete must be false. but there is no appid property on the Camel RabbitMQ consumer properties.